# Is @nuxtjs/hapi available for Node 18 ? (Nuxt 3, Vue 3)

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, hapi

I'm working on the migration fo project to Node 18, which uses Vue 3, Nuxt 3 and the backend in the same server built with node and hapi. This project originally uses @nuxt/hapi, but it seems it is not compatible with Node 18 anymore.

Any information about this?